# using imageFilter blur and clipping the element in same renderObject

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to use image filter blur on the child in the stack by creating a new RenderObject by myself. I have to use the renderObject for some reason, so i can't use the prebuilt (Backdrop filter and ClipPath) widgets.

here is the code:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter image filter blur demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const Demo(),
    );
  }
}

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Demo({super.key});

  @override
  State<Demo> createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  Offset offset = Offset.zero;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // if i comment this it will clip the element
          const Text("hello welcome to the demo of the backdrop blur"),
          Positioned(
            top: offset.dy,
            left: offset.dx,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onPanUpdate: (d) {
                setState(() {
                  offset += d.delta;
                });
              },
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: Blur(
                    child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3),
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Blur extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const Blur({
    Key? key,
    Widget? child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderBlur();
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, RenderBlur renderObject) {}
}

class RenderBlur extends RenderProxyBox {
  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
      //paint child
    context.paintChild(child!, offset);

    final blurLayer = BackdropFilterLayer(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcOver,
    );
    final clipLayer = ClipPathLayer(
      clipPath: Path()..addRect(offset & size),
    );

    context.addLayer(blurLayer);
    context.addLayer(clipLayer);

    // needs to `Path`

    super.paint(context, offset);
  }
}
```

result:[image]

by commenting the first child of stack it works fine as expected:

[image]

Comment: yes it has same size.

Comment: you are calling `super.paint` twice, you should do it only once, for example you call `pushClipPath` with a callback that calls `pushLayer`

Comment: @pskink edited the question with updated code. but issue remains.

Comment: I mean you should use twice `pushLayer`: first with a callback that call second `pushLayer` - this one should use `super.paint` as a callback

Comment: @pskink solved it. thank you very much for the help as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so the problem is:

1. In this case the `Stack` doesn't actually fill the screen. It fits to its children's size, which in this case is the `Text` size. You'd want to wrap it in `SizedBox()` or something so it fills the screen.
2. You want to blur the background, but only inside the bounds. So, what you want to do is add blur layer inside the painter of the clip layer.

So here's what I think you wanted to do:

[image: corrected screenshot]

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter image filter blur demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const Demo(),
    );
  }
}

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Demo({super.key});

  @override
  State<Demo> createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  Offset offset = Offset.zero;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            const Text("hello welcome to the demo of the backdrop blur"),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: offset,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (d) {
                  setState(() {
                    offset += d.delta;
                  });
                },
                child: Blur(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Blur extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const Blur({
    Key? key,
    Widget? child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderBlur();
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, RenderBlur renderObject) {}
}

class RenderBlur extends RenderProxyBox {
  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    final blurLayer = BackdropFilterLayer(
      filter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcOver,
    );
    final clipLayer = ClipPathLayer(
      clipPath: Path()..addRect(offset & size),
    );
    context.pushLayer(clipLayer, (context, offset) {
      context.addLayer(blurLayer);
      super.paint(context, offset); // This probably shouldn't be here, I don't know what you wanted so just try and move it around.
    }, offset);
  }
}
```